# Faraday Effect does light bend or lose energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, visible-light, photons

I was reading upon Faraday effect when it said

> Faraday effect causes a rotation of the plane of polarization

That in mind, does this mean the light can be bent around or does the light loose energy when its waves rotate? Can someone explain more about this effect simply as I'm a middle school going kid, make sure the explanation is simple yet precise please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That in mind, does this mean the light can be bent around or does the light loose energy when its waves rotate?

This answer expands on the previous one by user3814483 .

You must be familiar with the fact that light is composed of alternating electric and magnetic fields propagating in space whether there is a medium or not.

[image: emwave]

> The [electromagnetic waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave) that compose electromagnetic radiation can be imagined as a self-propagating transverse oscillating wave of electric and magnetic fields. This diagram shows a plane linearly polarized EMR wave propagating from left to right. The electric field is in a vertical plane and the magnetic field in a horizontal plane. The electric and magnetic fields in EMR waves are always in phase and at 90 degrees to each other.

The direction of the electric field is taken as the polarization direction, and the wave is polarized if it is uniformly so throughout its extent.

The [Faraday effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_effect) does not affect the energy of the beam of light, just the direction in the vertical to the motion plane, of the electric and magnetic fields, so it does not change the direction in which the energy propagates, which is given by the cross product of electric and magnetic fields.

So in this case the light does not bend around or lose energy . Polarization of light is [measurable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer), and the effect changes it.

Light can bend  in diffraction when entering a medium, and  in a suitable medium, it can bend as the medium bends, as happens in the [optical fiber cables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_fiber_cable) widely used for phone lines, and not only, ( but that is another story). No energy is lost in transparent media usually, otherwise they would not be transparent.

Answer (score 1):

The Faraday effect occurs because the phase speed of left-circularly polarized waves can be different than right-circularly polarized waves in certain media.  You can think of a linearly polarized electromagnetic wave as a superposition of left and right hand circularly polarized waves.

You can visualize how a left and right hand circularly polarized wave give rise to a linearly polarized wave [here](http://www.enzim.hu/~szia/cddemo/edemo8.htm).

So if one component travels faster than the other, this can cause a rotation of the electric field vector of the sum (the linearly polarized wave) as it travels through the medium.

Strictly speaking, this has little to do with wave damping or absorption; nor is light "bent around"